# Uma variável pode receber uma condicional?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de fazer com que a variável `pvs` recebesse uma condicional em que se o valor de outra variável (`resist`) multiplicado por 5 e, se e o valor da variável `resist` for zero, a variável `pvs` receba 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: A resposta abaixo não é o melhor exemplo de como fazer (e por isso nem deveria ter sido marcada como correta), pois `pvs = print(...)` não faz o menor sentido, já que `print` retorna `None`, então a variável não vai ter nenhum valor significativo nesse contexto. Se vc só quer imprimir o resultado, um simples `if condicao: print(uma coisa) else: print(outra coisa)` é mais que suficiente. Se quer guardar o valor, aí seria `if condicao: pvs = 'algum texto' else: pvs = 'outro texto'` (e no final vc pode imprimir `pvs`, por exemplo)

Comment: Provavelmente o que vc precisa é algo assim: https://ideone.com/uZQxMV - repare que atribuir um valor é diferente de imprimir o valor (mais um motivo para `pvs = print(...)` não fazer o menor sentido). Perceba que `pvs` não "recebe a condicional" (ou seja, ela não recebe o `if`). Ela recebe um valor ou outro dependendo da condição (se cair no `if` recebe um valor, se cair no `else` recebe outro). Depois, no final, vc faz o que quiser com esse valor (podendo, inclusive, imprimir). Dito isso, a resposta abaixo é tão errada, e desensina num nível tão absurdo que nunca deveria ter sido aceita...

Comment: Agradeço o feedback! Estou iniciando em programação, arriscando com ideias próprias e cursos gratuitos para aprender e melhorar. Muito obrigado pelo retorno, adequei meu código a suas recomendações e esclarecimentos!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você precisa definir primeiro o resultado antes de declarar o teste lógico! Exemplo literal de teste lógico: O personagem tem 1 ponto de vida `if resist == 0` (Caso contrário) `else` O personagem tem X pontos de vida.

Exemplo do código:

```
resist = 5
pvs = print("O personagem possui 1 ponto de vida") if resist == 0 else print(
    f'O personagem possui {resist * 5} pontos de vida')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Mas pra que atribuir a `pvs`? A função print não retorna nada, a variável ficará vazia.